# Pattern not found: ^M however it shows in git diff

Tags: git, vim, file-type

I recently edited a file, and encountered ^M at the end of the edited line, but only when I view the *git* (not eclipse) diff. If I search for ^M or try substitute it using

```
:%s/^V^M//g
```

but it tells me  "Pattern not found: ^M". I'm finding this extremely frustrating. Has anyone encountered this before (where *git* says one thing and vim another), and how does one resolve it?

Comment: JFTR, to enter `^M` in vim, press `Ctrl-v` then hit the Return/Enter key.

Answer (score 2):

`^M` is how vim renders a windows newline on Linux/UNIX. You can remove all occurrences in a file using the following command:

```
:%s/\r//
```

Comment: same result. pattern not found \r